# Javascript: Listing all globals set on a page? Webkit mainly

Tags: javascript, testing, webkit, phantomjs

For testing purposes, I would like to list all the globals set on a page. Initially the only browser I need to run this code is PhantomJS (webkit based). But I may need to run that on IE and Firefox later, if possible.

what i have so far is:

```
windowKnowAttributes = ['history','locationbar'....] // this will get huge.
for( v in window ){
    if( window.hasOwnProperty(v) ) //AND
    if( windowKnowAttributes.indexOf(v) === -1 )
        console.log(v)
}
```

Comment: http://remysharp.com/2007/11/01/detect-global-variables/

Comment: @san.chez interesting. instead of generating the initial list by being run before the state is 'dirty' it creates a new iframe at the execution moment to get a clean state for comparission. clever. But's it's still the same idea, roughtly...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter()` to compare your array of known properties to the current set of properties on the window object...perhaps like so:

```
var windowKnownProperties = ['history','locationbar'....]
var windowAllProperties = [];
for( v in window ){
    windowAllProperties.push(v);
}

var unknownGlobals = windowAllProperties.filter(function(el, idx, arr) {
    return (windowKnownProperties.indexOf(el) === -1);
});
```

You'll probably want to wrap things in a function so that the variables used here don't wind up in the global space themselves. You can also generate `windowKnownProperties` with a `for...in` loop before any other scripts run, then make a new array of `window` properties after the page has loaded and compare them with the `Array.filter()` method.

Comment: I think it's my fault that the question was badly written... filtering the array is not a problem. more interested in knowing a safer way to exclude the DOM elements from `window` than storing a first snapshot. but i think all the solutions does this, so there may not be a way around that.